# Pandas Merge of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I am looking to compare a group of data to the rolled up aggregate of that data.

In the example below, I want to know how much money each restaurant makes as compared to the total for all restaurants.  I want to know this by day.  If a restaurant is closed that day, I still want to return the name of the day and the name of the restaurant with a NaN (or a zero) for the total bill column.

*(I know that there are other ways to do this, but please consider this a question on merging, as there is a reason it needs to be done with two different dataframes)*

So, the output I would want is:

```
day   total_bill_x   restaurant   total_bill_y

Fri        651.76   DINER A     325.88 
Sat      3,556.80   DINER A   1,778.40 
Sun      1,627.16   DINER A        NaN 
Thur     2,192.66   DINER A   1,096.33
```

But the furthest I can get would return something like the following due to the nature of how outer joins work:

```
day   total_bill_x   restaurant   total_bill_y

Fri        651.76   DINER A   325.88 
Sat      3,556.80   DINER A   1,778.40 
Sun      1,627.16   NaN        NaN 
Thur     2,192.66   DINER A   1,096.33
```

The problem is that there is no merge that I can think of that would support this type of output - DINER A will just disappear if there isn't a match.

It gets worse with my real data set, which will consist of dozens of restaurants.

Is it possible to do an outer join that would grab fields from the table being joined to if there isn't match?  How can I see all of the records from the larger table for the records in the smaller table where there isn't a match?

I think it is an interesting problem and definitely interested in how others would handle.. Thanks!

Sample Code Follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/master/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')
df2=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/master/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')

df=df[df['day']!="Sun"]
df['restaurant']="DINER A"
df3=df.append(df2)
df_output=df.groupby(['restaurant','day'])[['total_bill']].sum().reset_index()
df_output2=df3.groupby(['day'])[['total_bill']].sum().reset_index()

pd.merge(df_output2,df_output, on='day', how="outer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## setup

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/master/ch08/tips.csv", sep=',')

d1 = pd.concat([df.query('day != "Sun"'), df], keys=['DINER A', 'DINER B']) \
    .rename_axis(['restaurant', None]).reset_index('restaurant')
```

## build a `pd.MultiIndex` with all restaurants and days

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        d1.restaurant.unique(),
        d1.day.unique()
    ], names=['restaurant', 'day'])
```

## do `groupby` + `join` + `reindex`

```
d2 = d1.groupby(['day']).total_bill.sum()
d3 = d1.groupby(['restaurant', 'day'])[['total_bill']].sum()

d3.reindex(mux).join(d2, lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y').reset_index()

  restaurant   day  total_bill_x  total_bill_y
0    DINER A   Sat       1778.40       3556.80
1    DINER A  Thur       1096.33       2192.66
2    DINER A   Fri        325.88        651.76
3    DINER A   Sun           NaN       1627.16
4    DINER B   Sat       1778.40       3556.80
5    DINER B  Thur       1096.33       2192.66
6    DINER B   Fri        325.88        651.76
7    DINER B   Sun       1627.16       1627.16
```

Comment: This is interesting - thank you, but one question - total_bill_y should always be total per day, but it is NaN in this instance for Diner A, Sunday.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps. First map the values of total bill for restaurant A to df_output2

```
df_output2['DINER_A'] = df_output2['day'].map(df_output.set_index('day')['total_bill'])
```

gives you

```
    day     total_bill  DINER_A
0   Fri     651.76      325.88
1   Sat     3556.80     1778.40
2   Sun     1627.16     NaN
3   Thur    2192.66     1096.33
```

Now melt the DINER_A column to create two columns restaurant and total_bill

```
df_output2 = pd.melt(df_output2, id_vars=['day', 'total_bill'],var_name="restaurant", value_name="total_bill_A")
```

You get

```
    day    total_bill   restaurant  total_bill_A
0   Fri    651.76       DINER_A     325.88
1   Sat    3556.80      DINER_A     1778.40
2   Sun    1627.16      DINER_A     NaN
3   Thur   2192.66      DINER_A     1096.33
```